# PHP Object is destroyed

Tags: php, testlink

I am upgrading `testlink` (1.9.4 to 1.9.17). The older version uses `php5` and the latest one uses `php7`.

My bellow code *(putting partial lines)* stopped working as the object is losing its value at `fetchFirstRow` on line #5.

If I comment `fetchFirstRow` then object `$db` loses its value in `readFromDB` on line #3.

Can someone help me in what is going wrong? The same thing works without any errors in the older version.

```
doDBConnect($db)
doDBConnect(&$db){
    $db=new database();  //Create database class 
}

myfunction(&$db){
    $user->readFromDB($db);
}

readFromDB(&$db){
    var_dump($db);  //Shows DB object
    $info = $db-> fetchFirstRow($sql);
    var_dump($db); //Shows nothing (Object gets destroued and web page looks like 404 page). 
}


function fetchFirstRow($sql){
    $result = $this->exec_query($sql);
    $row = null;
    if ($result){
      $row = $this->fetch_array($result);
    }
    unset($result);
    //var_dump($this->db);die();    //If unset is not commentd then this 
    return $row;
  }
```

Comment: I had no idea functions can be defined / used how you are using them, are you sure that is valid?

Comment: @Script47 The functions are scattered across class. fetchFirstRow is part of database class whose object is getting created in line 4 of example.

Comment: The only thing I can see in your code that could destroy a reference is unset(). Have you tried running exec_query and fetch_array outside fetchFirstRow()?

Comment: @Patrick, I tried commenting unset (though it is destroying $result and not $this) but the values of $db is still gone after this function is over. I have mention that in my problem statement,